# Producing multiple pytest fixtures

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am testing some engineering equations with several parameters that return arrays of floats. To test all of the cases, I would like to use a number of fixtures. I currently, store the test cases in a simple file, load them, and then return the test case of interest. Is there a better way to do this?

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[0, 1, 2])
def test_case(request):
    fpath = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
    fpath /= 'test_data' / 'test_cases.json'
    test_cases = json.load(fpath.open())
    return test_cases[request.param]

def test_function(test_case):
    # Run the test
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question.
Why not just inline the arrays in the python file?

Comment: Because the data in the Python file is pretty complex

Comment: You mean the JSON file? If yes, and you have to keep the data in JSON files, then this is pretty much it. You can make slight improvements to this code by for example using the `pytest_generate_tests` hook to scan the directory and run tests for every file there. That way you when you create a new JSON file it will be added to the tests automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pytest_generate_tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example).

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'test_case' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        fpath = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
        fpath /= 'test_data' / 'test_cases.json'
        test_cases = json.load(fpath.open())
        metafunc.fixturenames.append('test_case')
        metafunc.parametrize(
            'test_case',
            test_cases)
```

Comment: But in fact it won't improve anything..
Could you clarify why exactly you want 'better way', what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: I was only looking for ways to improve my approach/style. I couldn't find any documentation regarding generating multiple tests like I am, so I thought I might be thinking about the problem incorrectly.